# Android Camera getSupportedPreviewSizes() error

Tags: android, camera, screen-resolution

I am testing my Android app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab.  When I open up the camera application on the tablet, I see that the possible resolutions you can set for the camera are:

- 2560 x 1920
- 2560 x 1440
- 2048 x 1536
- 2048 x 1152
- 1600 x 1200
- 1536 x 864
- 640 x 480

However, when I open up a camera instance in my Android app and fetch the supported preview sizes, I get the following resolutions:

- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 720
- 1024 x 576
- 768 x 512
- 640  480
- 352 x 288
- 320 x 240

Why is there such a discrepancy in the supported resolutions?  I want my custom camera activity to have a full screen camera, and I can't do it with resolutions that are smaller than the screen size (which my app says is 800 x 1344).

```
    // fetch screen size
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels+navBarHeight;
    Log.d(TAG, "screen width and height: " + width + " " + height);

    // get supported preview sizes
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for(int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++){
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if(cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
            try {
                c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
                for(int i =0; i< c.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().size(); i++){
                    Size size = c.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "supported preview size: " + size.width + " " + size.height);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(cameraCount == 1 && cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)          {
            // device only has a front facing camera
            try {
                c = Camera.open(camIdx); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there such a discrepancy in the supported resolutions?

Picture resolutions and preview resolutions are not the same thing. The former is for pictures. The latter is for the preview frames.

> I want my custom camera activity to have a full screen camera, and I can't do it with resolutions that are smaller than the screen size (which my app says is 800 x 1344).

Yes, you can. Android will happily stretch or shrink your preview frames to match the size of the `TextureView` or `SurfaceView` that you are using for the preview. In fact, such stretching or shrinking is pretty much unavoidable, since it is rather unlikely that the camera will support some arbitrary preview resolution, one that happens to match whatever you are choosing for your preview `View` size.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  I have my cameraPreview in a FrameLayout and set the camerPreview to be one of the supported preview sizes.  How do I then get it to stretch to fit in the FrameLayout?

Comment: @scientiffic: The same way you get anything to fill a `FrameLayout`: set the width and height of the `TextureView` or `SurfaceView` to `match_parent`. Whether that's the right answer overall depends a bit on how you are sizing the `FrameLayout`. Bear in mind that a camera preview that is "full screen" really is *bigger* than the screen, as the aspect ratio of the screen rarely equals the aspect ratio of the preview frames. I had to do some fancy footwork in [my camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to make all that work.