# is Camera.getSupportedPreviewSizes guaranteed to include the display size

Tags: android, android-camera

Is Android's Camera.getSupportedPreviewSizes guaranteed to include the size of the device display?

I tested on several devices and this seems to be the case, but I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25221558/3326331)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not. Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727836/camera-display-preview-in-full-screen-does-not-maintain-aspect-ratio-image-i) which gives an example of a (front) camera not matching the display pixel size.

Comment: One negative example is certainly enough.